# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()

Tags: c#

I'd like to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` to process some strings in my application, but for some reason Visual Studio doesn't seem to know where it's at.

I'm fairly new to C# so I'm just guessing I've missed something like importing a library, but I don't even know what to Google.

I've tried `using System.Web` but it only seems to contain `AspNetHostingPermission` and friends, no `HttpUtility`.

I'm using VS2015 Community Edition on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I would start by googling the error message the IDE is telling me.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate, let me know if the solutions in the duplicate dont work...

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that did the trick. I've only started C# a few weeks ago, I hadn't come across an Assembly I had to reference until now.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried "using System.Web" but it only seems to contain "AspNetHostingPermission" and friends, no HttpUtility.

You simply need to reference the DLL `System.Web`, right click References > Add Reference > Assemblies > Framework > System.Web

Also check you're not targeting the Client Profile, in which System.Web.dll is not available. You can target the full framework in Project Properties.